# Google Java Format + Verify Google Java Format Combination Isn't Working Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to gradle; I just added it to my [main repository](https://github.com/nishantc1527/Algorithms) to see how it works. Here is how my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'

    id 'application'

    id 'com.github.sherter.google-java-format' version '0.8'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['jblas-1.2.4.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'sorting.bubblesort.BubbleSort'
}
```

As you can see, I applied a plugin called `google-java-format`. However, I am running into a problem with the two tasks:

```
googleJavaFormat
verifyGoogleJavaFormat
```

I can run `googleJavaFormat`, and it says it runs successfully. However, right after that, `verifyGoogleJavaFormat` says that it wasn't formatted correctly. Here is the only file that is apparently not formatted correctly:

```
package DataStructures.MinPriorityQueue;

import datastructures.minpriorityqueue.MinHeap.MinHeap;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MinHeapTest {
  @Test
  public void containsTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
      MinHeap<Integer> heap = new MinHeap<>(Integer::compare);
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
          set.add(j);
          heap.add(j);
        }
      for (Integer integer : set) assertTrue(heap.contains(integer));
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void isEmptyTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      MinHeap<Integer> heap = new MinHeap<>(Integer::compare);
      assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());
      int randomAmount = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
      for (int j = 0; j < randomAmount; j++) heap.add((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
      assertFalse(heap.isEmpty());
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void extractMinTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(Integer::compare);
      MinHeap<Integer> heap = new MinHeap<>(Integer::compare);
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
          priorityQueue.add(j);
          heap.add(j);
        }
      assertEquals(priorityQueue.poll(), heap.extractMin());
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void chainedExtractMinTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      int[] toAdd = new int[1000];
      MinHeap<Integer> heap = new MinHeap<>(Integer::compare);
      for (int j = 0; j < toAdd.length; j++) {
        toAdd[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        heap.add(toAdd[j]);
      }
      int[] sorted = toAdd.clone();
      Arrays.sort(sorted);
      int[] heapValues = new int[1000];
      for (int j = 0; j < heapValues.length; j++) heapValues[j] = heap.extractMin();
      assertArrayEquals(sorted, heapValues);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void decreaseKeyTest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      MinHeap<Integer> heap = new MinHeap<>(Integer::compare);
      PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Integer::compare);
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) heap.add(j);
      for (Integer j : heap) heap.decreaseValue(j, (int) (Math.random() * j));
      for (Integer j : heap) queue.add(j);
      while (!heap.isEmpty()) assertEquals(queue.poll(), heap.extractMin());
    }
  }
}
```

Even after I run `googleJavaFormat` on this file, `verifyGoogleJavaFormat` isn't successful. Why is this happening?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, what are you trying to do with those two tasks? Format it, and then verify that it's formatted? Are you sure that's possible? Why don't you simply want to ensure it is formatted?

Comment: @Andy Turner No, for the build to succeed it needs to be formatted correctly. So if it's not formatted the build fails.

Comment: your code isn't google-style formatted: the optional braces are missing.

Comment: @Andy Turner You mean the 1-line if statements? I don't know google-java-style, so I'll try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got my answer. Since I'm using Intellij, it moves around the imports. For example, whenever it sees a star * in the imports, it expands it. I just turned of File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import and uncheck optimize imports on the fly.